# Is there a way to define the resources to be cached on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat8, tomcat9

I had lots of warnings starting my app on Tomcat due to the small size of the static resources cache that Tomcat uses. I fixed this issue by simply increasing the cache size by adding **cacheMaxSize="100000"** to the resources block in the "context.xml" file of Tomcat.

My question is: is there a way to tell Tomcat what resources need to be cached? I saw on Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html) that you can configure PreResources, PostResources..etc but what about the main resources? what does it represent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation you cite](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html) the only criterion available is `cacheObjectMaxSize`. Resources up to this size will be cached regardless on where they are located.

[`WebResourceSet`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/WebResourceSet.html)s only provide a way to add to the application's root resources that are not physically contained in the **main** `WebResourceSet` (WAR file or directory).